# Find user that created instance

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I am having a hard time finding a way to list instances and, more importantly, the user that created them respectively.

Going through the hundreds of options inside the activity logs has yet to turn up anything concrete for me as it seems sometimes this data is recorded and other times it is not.

The end goal is to be able to find any resource that is created and whom created it (be it user or a group) so that tags can be issued to each resource allowing for easy separation of resources by the groups that are responsible for them.

Is anyone aware of a way to display this data or if it is even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say instance, do you mean a virtual machine instance?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more specific.

Comment: @JamesBolton The instances, do you mean VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance? Do you mean Azure VM? If yes, you could find who create it on Activity log. Note: You only could search log within 90 days if you don't save log to storage account.

You could search it as below:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! You answered another question I had regarding the 90 day retention of the logs too.